# How to hide a button in .net 2010?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-controls

I have a simple web for that has a dropdown list and a button on the form.
The dropdown list is bound to a table in my database and holds three values with idents between 1 and 3 (Weekly, Monthly, Please Select).

I have set my datasource to pull back item 3 (Please Select) as the first item in the dropdown list to prompt the user to select an option.  Items 1 & 2 have data assigned to them and this pulls back the relevent data for these options.

Here is my problem.  I need to hide my button when the page loads until the user selects item 1 or 2 and would like the button to be hidden of option 3 is selected.  I have tried to complete this in my page load event and the code for the dropdown list but i cannot seem to get this to work.

```
    If IsNumeric(DropDownList1.SelectedValue) = 3 Then
        btnAddAgendaTemplate.Visible = False
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the compare to:

```
   If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "3" Then
        btnAddAgendaTemplate.Visible = False
    End If
```

The function [`IsNumberic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6cd3f6w1(VS.90).aspx) just confirm if this is number or not and not convert it to number, and not compare it with the 3. Now the SelectedValue is a string, so direct compare it with the "3", no reason to convert it to number as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: (based on the comment)
In Selected Index changed event for the drop down check for the selectedvalue to be 3 and process accordingly

Suppose your selectedIndexChanged event is like this in your code behind:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
 If DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Equals("3") Then
     btnAddAgendaTemplate.Visible = False
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Habib,  if i just add btnAddAgendaTemplate.Visible = False to the page load event, this hides the button fully.  When my user selects option 1 or option two they have no submit button.  I am just wanting to hide the button when a user has selected option 3.  And three is the default option when a user opens the page.

Comment: @Betty, in that case you need to change only the selectedindexchanged event, I have update the answer, check now

Answer (score 0):

In page load event write following code

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack() Then
//Set default value in drop down list as 3
End
```

and

Write selection index changed event of drop down and write following code inside it.

```
If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "3" Then
    btnAddAgendaTemplate.Visible = False
ELSE
    btnAddAgendaTemplate.Visible = True
END
```

Comment: You'll also want to make sure that the autopostback property for your drop down list is set to 'True'.

Comment: And you'll need to set the visible property of the button to False in the designer, so that it isn't visible at the beginning.